# apache proxy for websocket not working from inside network

Tags: websocket, mod-proxy

We have a public URL public.test.com, this url is using a websocket{this ws is behind the apache proxy}, 
Now if i access this URL from out side out network, it is working perfect. But from inside network, it shows error

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://autoctest.test.com/Server.php' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Upgrade' header is missing
```

Webproxy/WS settings

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName autoctest.test.com

    ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/ws-error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/ws-access.log" common

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/Server.php           [NC]
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
  RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:9000/$1 [P,L]

  ProxyPass "/"  "http://localhost:9000/"
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Header information of unsuccessful request

```
client repose 
no work
GET /Server.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5------
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate-------
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Origin: http://sandbox.test.com
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate
Sec-WebSocket-Key: PHaOD9KhE5EUbKnCio/dLw==
Cookie: __gads=ID=c4832779adeab283:T=1406027066:S=ALNI_MY9sl2xL1vWSYt10kZDi8EteqGsXQ; __utma=99820289.827854179.1418281741.1455865287.1456480715.2; __utmz=99820289.1455865287.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); rzJSrchN=linux%2523%2523HHHCyber%2BInternet%2BServices%2523%2523HHHNakisa%2BSolutions%2523%2523HHHrozee%2523%2523HHHphp%2523%2523HHHnaseeb%2523%2523HHHphp%2523%25231185HHHjyfgjhyfj%2523%2523; rzSocialCookie=id%3D5323%23%21%23fbuid%3D%23%21%23liuid%3D5e4JkSjPx_; _ga=GA1.2.827854179.1418281741; rzCVSrchN=muhammad%2Baamir%2BnaveedHHHsanHHHphp%2Bdeveloper%255C%255CHHHlinuxHHHsolaris; __cfduid=dcdf18ce9461b4c6f88b0f4898c667a151463393386; csPageSize=16; seeker_overlay=89912915819191; _ceg.s=o6w8zz; _ceg.u=o6w8zz; _gat=1
Pragma: no-cache
Via: 1.1 network (squid)
X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.1.210, 122.129.76.12 ------
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Forwarded-Host: autoctest.test.com
X-Forwarded-Server: autoctest.test.com
Upgrade: WebSocket
Connection: Upgrade

Server response 
HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake
Upgrade: WebSocket
Connection: Upgrade
WebSocket-Origin: sandbox.test.com
WebSocket-Location: ws://sandbox.test.com:9000/shout.php
Sec-WebSocket-Accept:a6aaX24wCJ+vqXw2YWOkpfjMuBs=
```